# Dataset filter method

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Here is my code,

```
Conn.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from CurrentDataCR ",Conn);

SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

sqlDa.Fill(ds);

ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = " mst_remote_station_id Like'*9001*'";
```

Here I am getting Complete row for id 9001. I need only one column value for this id.

Comment: Can't you just select the column you need in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[0].Select("mst_remote_station_id Like '%9001%'");
```

You can do it this way also if you need only one row just select it in the initial query.

**Also you should Dispose the SqlDataAdapter after using it !** You can do it with using block

```
Conn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from CurrentDataCR ",Conn);

using(SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
{
    sqlDa.Fill(ds);
}
ds.Tables[0].Select("mst_remote_station_id Like '%9001%'");
```

I don't know if the connection is global but it is bad practice to use global connection, you have connection pool so use separate connection for every query.

Comment: I dont need whole row i need only one value from the row for id 9001

Comment: So take the value which you need with **rows[0]["ColumnName"]** what is the problem ?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get u, can u plese give one example

Comment: DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[0].Select("TotalDischarge where mst_remote_station_id = '*9001*'");
Here i get error as Missing Operand near where.

Comment: Do you see somewhere in my code where in the select ? Atleast read the answer fully.

Comment: Sorry but I m trying to use where

Comment: Please read what is doing Select, it is adding WHERE AUTOMATICALLY. I'm stopping explain anythign.

Comment: hey i need one help, I got what u r saying but i used this query in my code   ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = " mst_remote_station_id Like '*9001*'";

Comment: But for second textbox when i fire same query with diifernt id in gives me record of first id in textbox.